# Sorting numbers with a simplified bubble style sort isn’t returning the second smallest value

Tags: java, sorting

In this code, I needed to find the first and second smallest number of the ones generated I also need to find the sum. So far I've managed to do everything except finding the second smallest number. How do you make sure the second smallest number is distinct from the smallest?

```
String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many iterations?");
int iter = Integer.parseInt(str);
String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the max in our range?");
int max = Integer.parseInt(str2);
String str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the minimum in our range?");
int min = Integer.parseInt(str3);
int numcache = max;
int numcache1 = max;

int sum = 0;

for (int a = 0; a <= (iter - 1); a = a + 1) {
    double out;

    out = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int output = (int) out;
    System.out.println(output);

    if (output < numcache) {
        numcache = output;
    }

    if (numcache < numcache1) {
        numcache1 = numcache;
    }

    sum = output + sum;

}
System.out.println("The 2nd smallest number is  " + numcache1);
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
System.out.println("The smallest number  is " + numcache);
```

Here is the output, with inputs 20; 10; 1

```
    4
    4
    8
    10
    2
    10
    10
    7
    2
    9
    7 
    8
    1
    10
    7
    6
    8
    4
    8
    6
    The 2nd smallest number is  1
    The sum is 131
    The smallest number  is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if` conditions as below

```
if (output < numcache) {
    numcache1 = numcache;
    numcache = output;
}
else if (output < numcache1) {
    numcache1 = output;
}
```

- In `true` case it will swap 1st smallest to 2nd as we found smaller number than 1st smaller.
- In `false` case it will only check for 2nd smallest number.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. For your output data: When your output is '1' it's smaller then the previous '2'. So numcache is 1. Next you check if your numcache is smaller than your numcache1. This is also true because numcache is now '1'(smallest value) and numcache1 is '2'. So numcache1 is set to '1' as well.

Solution: If numcache1 always have to be bigger than numcache you can just do this:

```
if (numcache + 1 < numcache1) {
    numcache1 = numcache;
}
```